# Customizing UIImagePickerController in camera mode

Tags: iphone

In camera mode tool bar shows on down of the screen with capture button. I want two more button in same tool bar on right and left position (info, photolibrary). Is it possible to achieve this. and if possible what is the chance of clean approval from Apple app store.

Looking for your suggestion......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**. You can't customize *UIImagePickerController* (and most of the in-built controllers) until there is some API available to do that, like *cameraOverlayView* property of *UIImagePickerController*.

Comment: Will this approach be allowed by apple app store

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily without using UIImagePickerController. Try using the [AVCam demo app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) provided by Apple. It has a UIView object called `videoPreviewView` which captures Camera's input and shows you the feed. You can see it in the AVCamViewController.xib file. It has simple methods to capture an image or a video if necessary. Now, you can customize a toolbar in the bottom of that view and add buttons to it and perform the functions you want on their click events. It is approved by Apple and faces no problem at all.